# Ember Piping Feature

Tags: ember.js

Does Ember have a similar feature to Angular2's Piping (https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html)? The closest thing I found were transforms, but that is strictly for the Datastore (DS). I want to convert text "Cat" to "Dog" everywhere, and I don't want to stick if statements everywhere. I can create a utility function to do this, but if there is a specific feature for this then I would like to use that.

Looking for something like this:

```
let a = "cat";
let b = a | animal; //animal should convert variable a to dog
console.log(a); // cat
console.log(b); // dog
```

I realize I can do something like this and stick it in the Utilities, but I want to do it the Ember way if there is one:

```
let animal = function(string) {
  if(a == "cat") {
    return "dog";
  }
}
```

Is there a built in feature of ember that will do this nicely for me?

Comment: Maybe create a helper? For things like date or price formatting this is the right tool.

Comment: Can helpers be used in services, utilities, and etc..? I thought they were for templates. If they can, can you give me a small example, and I'll accept it. I wasn't able to find any examples.